# Setting Password Protection on XSSF Workbook

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I would like to add password protection to a xlsx file created with poi 3.14.
The documentation claims, that this is possible:

http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html

Using the example I tried it like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try(Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook())
    {

        //<...>
        try(ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
        {
            wb.write(baos);
            byte[] res = baos.toByteArray();
            try(ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(res))
            {
                try(POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(bais);) // Exception happens here
                {
                    EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile);
                    Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
                    enc.confirmPassword("pass");
                    OutputStream encryptedDS = enc.getDataStream(fileSystem);
                    OPCPackage opc = OPCPackage.open(new File("example.xlsx"), PackageAccess.READ_WRITE);
                    opc.save(encryptedDS);
                    opc.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the code in the example is not compatible to XLSX files and as a result I receive the following exception:

```
The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
```

Can anybody help please? I am unable to find the correct alternative for XLSX...

Thank you all for you help. Here is my working result:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try(Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook())
    {
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet();
        Row r = sheet.createRow(0);
        Cell cell = r.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        cell.setCellValue("Test");
        try(POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem();)
        {
            EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.standard);
            Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
            enc.confirmPassword("pass");
            OutputStream encryptedDS = enc.getDataStream(fileSystem);
            wb.write(encryptedDS);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/example.xlsx");
            fileSystem.writeFilesystem(fos);
            fos.close(); 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is giving you that exception?

Comment: Is example.xslx (should be .xlsx) really an Office 2007+ XML file? You don't need to use OPCPackage but could simply copy the file bytewise to encryptedDS. But if example.xslx is for instance a Excel 2003 XML calculation sheet, opening the encrypted file wouldn't work either ....

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I marked the line in which the exception occures (new POIFSFileSystem). "xslx" was a typo..

Comment: Please [open a bug entry](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI) and attach your example.xlsx - I need to have a look onto this file

Comment: Hi, I filed https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60363 The example.xlsx does not exist, but this is irrelevant, the line is never executed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've mis-read the [documentation on encrypting in OOXML file](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#XML-based+formats+-+Encryption). You're therefore incorrectly trying to load your file using the wrong code, when you just need to save it

Without any error handling, your code basically wants to be

```
// Prepare
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.agile, CipherAlgorithm.aes192, HashAlgorithm.sha384, -1, -1, null);

Encryptor enc = info.getEncryptor();
enc.confirmPassword("foobaa");

// Create the normal workbook
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
Sheet s = wb.createSheet();
// TODO Populate

// Encrypt
OutputStream os = enc.getDataStream(fs);
wb.save(os);
opc.close();

// Save
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("protected.xlsx");
fs.writeFilesystem(fos);
fos.close();
```

Comment: Your code is not working on .NET using NPOI package. Could you plese tell me, what to do to make it working? I don't want install Java. ` POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(); EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.Agile, CipherAlgorithm.aes192, HashAlgorithm.sha384, -1, -1, null); Encryptor enc = info.Encryptor; enc.ConfirmPassword("foobaa"); /* <== Exception HERE: EncryptedDocumentException. Export Restrictions in place - please install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files. */

Comment: Try vary constructor parameters, e.g. just: ````var info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.Agile)```` Not all software environments know or allow all cipher/hash algorithms.