# Password protect opening Excel (xlsx) file using NPOI

Tags: c#, .net, excel, password-protection, npoi

How can I password protect opening Excel file (xlsx) file using NPOI?

Operating system is Windows 10 without Java installed, runtime platform is .NET 4.7.

There is class `EncryptionInfo` but there is no documentation how to use it, so please help me. I know that there is posibility to protect editing on `ISheet` using method `ProtectSheet`, but it is not, what I am looking for. I need protect opening. Is there an example code or documentation?

Comment: Look at the accepted answer posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40511701/setting-password-protection-on-xssf-workbook

Comment: @cly The code referred is not working for me. It is Java code and expects at least Java installed.


`
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.Agile, CipherAlgorithm.aes192, HashAlgorithm.sha384, -1, -1, null);

Encryptor enc = info.Encryptor;
enc.ConfirmPassword("foobaa");  /* <== Exception HERE: EncryptedDocumentException. Export Restrictions in place - please install JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files.
*/

Comment: NPOI and POI mostly same so do not skip examples automatically if you see Java code :) Try vary constructor parameters, e.g. just: ````var info = new EncryptionInfo(EncryptionMode.Agile)```` Not all software environments know or allow all cipher/hash algorithms.